# Bash Shell - problems with quoting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quote

I have a problem in this line:

```
--description=\""$(<$varLeer/media/festplatte/txt/$varDesc)\""
```

I want it to get out the following:

```
--description="$(<$varLeer/media/festplatte/txt/$varDesc)"
```

But how do I get it that it does not "make use" of the letters   `"$(<`   and   `)"`  ?
I hope you understand what I mean. I read this tutorial (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) but I don't understand how I can write down the "$(< and the )" without the shell using it "as Code".

To get maybe a bit clearer, I want to get the second code to be shwon but with the `"$(< )"` but marked as "real code".

What I tried is this - but it did not work:

```
--description=\"$(<"$varLeer/media/festplatte/txt/$varDesc\")"
```

//EDIT: Lets be much clearer at what I want to do.
There is a phyton script called "youtube-uploader" (https://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload/wiki/Readme). Now that I don't have to write "youtube-upload ....... *INSERT VERY MUCH HERE ;)*" every video I want that the uploaded parts get their title, description etc automatically. My idea was to just open my ytscript.bash with nano, edit the first top variables and then just do "sh ytscript.bash", insert my password and relax.

The part would be +1 every time the loop is used and with this there is automatically an own fitting title for every part. Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variablen
varSpielart="Lets Play: "
varSpielname="Diablo 3 "
varParttext="- PART "
varStartpart=1
varEndpart=2
varExtras=" [PS4][1080p]"
varKategorie=Games
varDesc="lpd3desc.txt"

varDateiname=lpd3
varDateiendung=.m4v
varKeywords="ps4, spieleule, piupload"
varPlaylist="UNDEFINIERT"

varAnzahlparts=`expr $varEndpart - $varStartpart`
varLeer=" "

echo "Gebe dein Passwort ein!"
read varPasswort

echo YT-UPLOAD: BEGINNE NEUEN UPLOAD
echo YT-UPLOAD: SPIEL $varSpielname
echo YT-UPLOAD: ANZAHL PARTS: $varAnzahlparts

varDurchgang=$varStartpart

while [ $varEndpart -gt $varDurchgang ]
do
cd youtube-upload
youtube-upload --email="email@email.de" --password=$varPasswort --private --category=$varKategorie --title=\""$varSpielart$varSpielname$varParttext$varDurchgang$varExtras\"" \
--description=$(<$varLeer/media/festplatte/txt/$varDesc) \
/media/festplatte/upload/$varDateiname"p"$varDurchgang""$varDateiendung &
varDurchgang=`expr $varDurchgang + 1`
echo Durchgang: $varDurchgang
echo Entpart: $varEndpart
echo Startpart: $varStartpart
echo Anzahlparts: $varAnzahlparts
done
```

The automatically title works like a charm (except giving me a " at the start and the end of the title on youtube.com without me wanting it! :( ). The description on youtube.com only gets a "" in it with the first answer under this question.

Comment: Why are you trying to put literal quotes there? Is this whole string going in variable? Are you just trying to get the description to be the whole contents? If that's what you want then just `--description="$(<"....")"` is what you want.

Comment: I suppose you can also always quote each single special character with a backslash, e.g. `--description=\"\$\(\<\$varLeer...`. But I may not understand properly what you want: What does "marked as real code" mean? The shell has no notion of "real code". It just performs (possibly built-in) commands on text arguments.

Comment: I added some (way) more infos to the question :)

Comment: You've added plenty of information but it's still unclear to me which parts should be expanded and which parts shouldn't.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want the string after `description` to actually contain. I can't see how `description=$(<something)` could be actually useful, but that really seems to be what you want. Is it really?

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes:

```
--description='"$(<$varLeer/media/festplatte/txt/$varDesc)"'
```

Comment: If I try this the variables ($varLeer and $varDesc) are not read anymore. I put some more infos into the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
temp='$(<'$varLeer'/media/festplatte/txt/'$varDesc')'

--description=$temp
```